# Mockito,JUNIT-->How can be stub out the SORT.BY parameter in when() and verify() calls?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit-jupiter

Below is the method from controller

```
@RequestMapping("addWorkout")
public  String addWorkout(ModelMap modelmap,HttpSession session) {
    LOGGER.info("Inside addWorkout,Start");
    int userId=(int)session.getAttribute("userId");
    // modelmap.addAttribute("userId",id);

    List<Workout> workoutList = workoutRepo.findByUserId(userId,Sort.by(new Sort.Order(Direction.DESC, "date"), new Sort.Order(Direction.DESC, "startTime")));
    modelmap.addAttribute("workoutList", workoutList);
    modelmap.addAttribute("exerciseList", exerciseRepo.findAll());
    LOGGER.info("Inside addWorkout,end");
    return "AddWorkout";
}
```

How do i write when call for below line of code?it could be any simple type of match for SORT parameter
 `workoutRepo.findByUserId(userId,Sort.by(new Sort.Order(Direction.DESC, "date"), new Sort.Order(Direction.DESC, "startTime")));`

Below is the test method i have written for the above controller method

```
@Test
void addWorkoutTest() {
    int userId = 1;

    List<Workout> mockWorkoutList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Exercise> mockExerciseList = new ArrayList<>();
    when(exerciseRepo.findAll()).thenReturn(mockExerciseList);
    when(session.getAttribute("userId")).thenReturn(userId);
    String result = workoutController.addWorkout(modelMap, session);
    verify(exerciseRepo, times(1)).findAll();
    verify(session, times(1)).getAttribute("userId");
    verify(modelMap, times(1)).addAttribute("workoutList", mockWorkoutList);
    verify(modelMap, times(1)).addAttribute("exerciseList", mockExerciseList);
    assertNotNull(result);
}`
```

i am unsure how to handle the SORT parameter part.Looking for different ways to handle the SORT parameter in when() call.Any examples will help me learn

`when(workoutRepo.findByUserId(anyInt(),     ) ).thenReturn(mockWorkoutList);`

Comment: I'm confused by your question. If you `when(workoutRepo…)`, then you shouldn't call `workoutRepo` in your test. What would you be testing then? That Mockito can stub calls?

Comment: how do i write a when() statement for below line of code? workoutRepo.findByUserId(userId,Sort.by(new Sort.Order(Direction.DESC,    "date"), new Sort.Order(Direction.DESC, "startTime")));

Comment: That depends on when you want your stubbed method call to be matched. Could be as simple as wrapping the expression in `when`, could be `when(…(any(), any(), any())`, or could be complicated with an `argThat(…)` matcher. Nevertheless, the test (`testMethod()`) that you show, calls the repo – so I'm asking what you are testing with your test? (nothing)

Comment: i have updated my question by adding controller methods and JUNIT method.Looking for simple when expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userId` is an int and [`Sort` overrides `boolean equals(Object)`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.java#L254), so you can match directly on the exact arguments:

```
when(workoutRepo.findByUserId(userId, Sort.by(new Sort.Order(Direction.DESC, "date"), new Sort.Order(Direction.DESC, "startTime"))))
    .thenReturn(List.of(…));
```

You can also use `eq` matchers (`Matchers.eq`):

```
when(workoutRepo.findByUserId(eq(userId), eq(Sort.by(new Sort.Order(Direction.DESC, "date"), new Sort.Order(Direction.DESC, "startTime")))))
    .thenReturn(List.of(…));
```

or match with `any()` if you don't care about the actual value:

```
when(workoutRepo.findByUserId(eq(userId), any()))
    .thenReturn(List.of(…));
```